# What is the asterisk on a data type in a Windows API declaration?

Tags: c, winapi

I know what (for example) a `DWORD` is, it's a four-byte unsigned long integer.

But what does `DWORD *` with an asterisk before the parameter name mean, as seen here:

```
HRESULT UrlUnescape(
  __inout      PTSTR pszURL,
  __out_opt    PTSTR pszUnescaped,
  __inout_opt  DWORD *pcchUnescaped,
  DWORD dwFlags
);
```

**UPDATE**

It occurs to me I had a few additional hints that it was a pointer. The first is that the parameter name starts with a *p*. The other is that it is an in/out parameter, and the only way the callee could alter the value of the caller's variable is if a pointer is passed rather than a value. Of course, the strings are pointers too, and they don't use the asterisk, but that's because a string *can't* be passed by value so it would be redundant, while an integer certainly can be passed by value (and often/usually is).

Comment: A better 1st question would be "what is a pointer in C?" - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016765/tutorial-on-c-pointers

Comment: @Steve That's silly! If my question was "what's that little hard cylindrical piece on the ends of a shoelace?" would you say "A better 1st question would be 'what is an aglet?'" I didn't *know* it was a pointer. That's why I asked.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you cannot learn the basics of the language by studying an API in C. If you know already all about pointers, then that's fine.

Comment: @Erik The Windows API is written in C. Are you saying you expect to understand it without knowing the basics of C first? Or can we expect lots of other questions from you in this line? Please, not.

Comment: @Steve Okay, but I'm not really trying to learn C. I'm actually using VB6. But that's immaterial;I didn't know what the asterisk meant. I already understand pointers and know how to translate the function call. Thank you for the link to more resources on pointers, anyway.

Comment: @unapersson I do expect to understand it. I've been using pointers since I was writing Pascal programs at age 11 or so. But I have written only about 20 lines of C code in my life. See my update for additional thoughts.

Comment: @Erik Learning C from the Hungarian notation used (sometimes) by MS is not  a good idea.

Comment: @unapersson Okay, when I some day set out to learn C I'll avoid treating the systems hungarian notation in parameter names of the Windows API documentation as definite in any way. Thanks for the tip, pardner! In the meantime, I have all I need to complete my task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that `pcchUnescaped` is pointer to an object of type `DWORD`.  That's normal C, nothing specifically related to the Windows API.

Comment: I wondered about that, I just couldn't find documentation of it anywhere. It's awfully hard to search for an asterisk.

Comment: And thank you for the edit, I agree it's much better to just inline the example code than give a link.

Comment: @Erik, the C spec section **6.7.5.1 Pointer declarators** might explain the syntax to you some more.  Any basic online C tutorial will have a section about pointers as well.

Answer (score 2):

It means a pointer to a `DWORD` in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

A DWORD is a 32-bit unsigned integer (range: 0 through 4294967295 decimal). Because a DWORD is unsigned, its first bit (Most Significant Bit (MSB)) is not reserved for signing.

Comment: Thanks for answering the apparent (original) title of my question, but this didn't answer my actual written question.